# How to append string with dash?

Tags: grep, string

I am trying to append create a string that will be evaluated in the middle of a grep line. It is to find possible occurrences of different usernames within a certain file. However, I do not know how many usernames there will be. So, I cycle through the array containing the list of usernames and return at output like so "-e username -e username2 -e username3" that will be used in the grep line.

However, this small piece of code seems to be giving me trouble. I've tried several approaches, but UNIX still believes I am trying to pass some sort of command:

```
eGrepUsernames(){
    returnString="";
    for username in "${usernames[@]}"
    do
        $returnString="$returnString -e $username" #error given, command not found
    done
    echo returnString;
}
```

Later, I call the function over here:

```
declare -a activeUsers=$( who | grep `eGrepUsernames` )
```

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: Drop the first $ -- returnString="......

Comment: This will not make the variable local to the for loop?

Comment: @SepiaSilver The `$` operator is the operator to expand a variable to its value. It's not a variable access operator so much as an "insert variable contents here" operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function was trying to evaluate `$returnString` on the left-hand side during the assignment; instead, you want:

```
eGrepUsernames(){
    returnString="";
    for username in "${usernames[@]}"
    do
        returnString="$returnString -e $username" # this line changed
    done
    printf '%s ' $returnString;  ## so did this one
}
```

Comment: Thank you - there is no error now, but strangely, "-e" is still not be appended to the string - only the username is.

Comment: we both got caught by `echo` seeing the `-e` as an option instead of as text to be printed. I updated the answer to use printf instead.

Comment: For some great background, see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/117549

Comment: Thank you for clearing up that massive misunderstanding and providing that resource!

Answer (score 1):

`declare` is a bash-only command, that's the equivalent of `typeset` in `ksh` or `zsh`.

`dash` has no equivalent command and has no array support other than with `"$@"`.

The way to go here is to store the list of user names in a newline delimited list:

```
users="me
you
someone"
```

And use:

```
who | grep -F "$users"
```

However, that will look for `me`, `you` or `someone` anywhere in the `who` output (note that `someone` does contain `me` for instance).

Some `grep` implementations have a `-w` to search for words only.

You would probably want to check for the first column of the `who` output (assuming none of your users have blanks in their user names):

```
users="me you someone"
grepUsernames() {
  awk -v u="$users" '
    BEGIN{split(u, a); for (i in a) users[a[i]]}
    $1 in users'
}
```